# excel formula: sum elements in column a where column b has an even number

Tags: excel, sum

I'm trying to come up with an excel formula which will sum those elements in column A for which the corresponding element in column B is an even number.  I've tried various permutations of sumif() without any luck so far.  Specifically, I'm not sure how to specify the criteria to match even numbers in cells in the range.  Or maybe there's another way entirely.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at combining the functions SUMPRODUCT and ISEVEN.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MOD and SUMIFS functions in this way:
[image: Solution]

The result is in the cell D1. Note that I have semicolons (;) instead of commas in the formula.

Comment: Thanks.   This morning as I was waking up I realized that adding a column simplified the problem, so this seems OK.  I'll also explore the suggestion by XOR LX in a comment to the original post.

Comment: No problem. You could probably cram the MOD condition directly into the SUMIFS formula, so you wouldn't need the extra column.